# npm Twitter library not authenticating?

Tags: node.js, twitter

I have this code

```
var Twitter = require('twitter');

var client = new Twitter({

        consumer_key: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
        consumer_secret: process.env.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
        access_token_key: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_KEY,
        access_token_secret: process.env.TWITTER_ACCESS_SECRET,
});


client.post('status/update', {status: 'Test'}, function(error,params,response){
    if(error) throw;
    console.log(params);
    console.log(response);
});
```

but it keeps just giving me this when i run node tweet.js

```
if(error) throw;
               ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
  at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
  at startup (node.js:119:16)
  at node.js:929:3
```

I am 100% sure that my environment variables are correct and exactly what they say on my dev twitter. So i am not sure what the problem is here or even how to approach it!

After fixing the syntax error and changing that line to `throw error;` the new problem is it is now this

```
    if(error) throw error;
                    ^
    [object Object]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code for `client.post`

```
client.post('status/update', {status: 'Test'}, function(error,params,response){
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(params);
    console.log(response);
});
```

Actually you forgot to `throw` the `error`. So there was a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

`error` in your case is not a standard javascript `Error` object and hence it cannot be thrown this way, you may check the value of `error` object and see what it contains and through `if` statement you can handle your actions, alternatively you may throw a custome error by issuing `throw 'OMG!';`